# Android UDP communication. Cannot receive a data from device

Tags: android

There is a physical device to which a phone can be connected using UDP protocol.
The problem is this: the electronics engineer who programmed the device wrote a desktop program that interacts with this device (using UDP also), and everything runs smoothly there: the device receives commands and sends responces without any problems and exceptions.

But with the phone - the trouble ... The phone connects to the device via WiFi without problems, sends commands without any problems too (no timeoutexception), but there is a problem with the receive - once the answer comes, the other does not come. In general socket.receive does not work as stable as on the desktop program very often pops up timeoutexception ...

I gave all permissions needed for it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

I run a command within an AsyncTask:

```
private class GetStatus extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, UdpResult> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    isPinging = true;

    if (udpSettingsListener != null) {
        udpSettingsListener.onPreGetStatus();
    }
}

@Override
protected UdpResult doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
    UdpResult udpResult = sendCommand(params[0]);
    udpResult.opName = "GetStatus";
    udpResult.odDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    udpResults.add(udpResult);
    return udpResult;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(UdpResult result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    isPinging = false;

    if (udpSettingsListener != null) {
        if (result.succeed) {
            udpSettingsListener.onGotStatus(new DeviceStatus(result.response));
        } else {
            udpSettingsListener.onFailedToGetStatus(result.exception);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the 'sendCommand' function which communicates with device:

```
private UdpResult sendCommand(byte[] command) {
UdpResult udpResponse = new UdpResult();
try {
    Thread.sleep(sleepFor);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
do {
    udpResponse.command = command;
    udpResponse.response = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setSendBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
        socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(udpResponse.command, BUFFER_SIZE, inetAddress, port);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(udpResponse.response, BUFFER_SIZE, inetAddress, port);
        socket.send(sendPacket);
        socket.receive(receivePacket);
        udpResponse.succeed = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sendCommand: ", e);
        udpResponse.succeed = false;
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    udpResponse.attempts++;
} while (udpResponse.attempts < maxAttempts && !udpResponse.succeed);
return udpResponse;
```

}

Here is the timeoutexception I receive:

```
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException  at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:598)  at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:556)  at
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163)
> at
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171)
> at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274)  at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper.sendCommand(UdpHelper.java:326)
> at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper.access$1400(UdpHelper.java:27)
> at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper$SetRtc.doInBackground(UdpHelper.java:371)
> at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper$SetRtc.doInBackground(UdpHelper.java:357)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  at
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  Caused by:
> android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: EAGAIN (Try again)  at
> libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)  at
> libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:185)  at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)  at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)  at
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163)*
> at
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171)*
> at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274)*  at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper.sendCommand(UdpHelper.java:326)*
> at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper.access$1400(UdpHelper.java:27)*
> at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper$SetRtc.doInBackground(UdpHelper.java:371)*
> at
> com.andreyserdyuk.gaash.helpers.UdpHelper$SetRtc.doInBackground(UdpHelper.java:357)*
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)*  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)*  at
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)*  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)*
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)*
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)*
```

Comment: maybe you should start receiving on a thread and then send from another thread, also, if for some reason the sent data doesnt arrive, the device might never send the response

Comment: Which port number do you use ?, only root system apps can listen on ports <1024

Comment: ipAddress - 192.168.1.1,
port - 8010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess that your timeout kicks in before the packet is sent. This means that the packet you are trying to sends is too large.

When you say: once the answer comes, the other does not come. It is not clear to me. My guess is that you receive one packet but the other one is not received.
One quick test is to increase the timeout. This would confirm of the packet to receive is too large.
My recommendation would be to try sending smaller packets. Have some debug points inserted in your android app to look for the problem?

Comment: BUFFER_SIZE is always 38 bytes. it's never changed.
38 bytes array - this is the fixed data size the device can send and receive.

Comment: Did you try to increase the timeout delay?